# Unable to connect to my SQL DB on Update-Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to learn MVC 5 using code first.

I moved all my entities to the domain project and currently referencing the Domain from the WebUi project. I have installed Ninject and MVC into both WebUI and the Domain projects. Also I have installed the Identity Entity Framework package into the Domain class as I still want to use the default roles and users class that comes with the mvc.

Currently having the problems below in the image. any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You shoudl supply a small example that we can actually see and use. A screen shoot that is too small to easily read makes diagnosis difficult. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for the screenshot and not enough code. I ended up figuring out that I did not have the necessary references within my domain library for it to work as expected. Adding in the library to both my WebUI and Domain projects solved my problem.